# Filter edges in a geometric network trace?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, filter, geometric-network, trace

I need to trace a geometric network of sewer pipes, but I'm only interested in storm pipes. More specifically storm pipes that connect directly to a starting flag, and not those downstream/upstream of another pipe-type. Each starting flag might have several pipes connected to it of different types (e.g. sanitary, storm, CSO, etc.). Unfortunately, I can't query out the storm pipes because traces only accept geometric networks and not feature layers.

[image]

I've been reading about "in_edge_along_digitized_weight_filter" (in trace geometric network tool), but I can't figure out how to use it. The drop-down box is empty for this option. My geometric network was not built with weights, so I'm guessing that's probably why.

[image]

I would like to avoid rebuilding the geometric network if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to edit your network features?  If so the easiest way to selectively trace features in a geometric network is to set them as Not Enabled (Enabled = False).

Every network feature will have a field called `Enabled` which you can set to `True` or `False` to indicate whether you want the trace to traverse those assets or not.  If you select all your non-Storm assets and set Enabled to `False`, and then select all Storm assets and set Enabled to `True`, your trace will only run on your Storm assets.

[image]

If you already have different features with Enabled set you may need to copy your network out to another database or perform your edit and trace in a version.  Once you've completed your trace you can always revert your Enabled values back.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was definitely over-complicating this problem. It takes forever to field calculate rows to disabled for the traces and back because of the size of our network, but this definitely solves the problem.